# Transpose data list

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a table which looks like this:

| Item# | Name | Value | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | John | $345 | 3 |
| 22 | John | $21 | 1 |
| 23 | John | $323 | 4 |
| 21 | Bob | $254 | 1 |
| 22 | Bob | $34 | 2 |
| 23 | Bob | $400 | 4 |
| 21 | Suzy | $254 | 9 |
| 22 | Suzy | $25 | 1 |
| 23 | Suzy | $202 | 15 |

and I wish to convert into something like this:

| Item | John | Bob | Suzy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item# | Value | Quantity | value | Value |
| ---------- | ------ | -------- | ------ | ------- |
| 21 | $345 | 3 | $254 | $254 |
| 22 | $21 | 1 | $34 | $25 |
| 23 | $323 | 4 | $400 | $202 |

How to transpose the table using VBA?

Comment: Have you tried using a pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

I think a Pivot Table will get you exactly where you want to go. Place your cursor anywhere within your data table, go to Insert > PivotTable > From Table/Range > Insert New Sheet.
The "PivotTable Fields" panel that opens on the right is not super-intuitive. Try dragging Item onto Rows and name onto Columns, and Value onto Values. This will almost replicate your sample above, instantly.
This is an incredibly powerful tool with many secret and hidden capabilities. You might want to search youTube for "excel pivot table essentials" or similar.